# Error Code When Jumping

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to learn assembly (specifically the nasm variety on ideone.com). When I jump to a procedure I'm getting error code 11, while when I just call the procedure there is no error. I've tried it with and without the "ret" at the end of the block. Note that the _printOne procedure is only called if the input is of length 2, e.g "a[newline]". Here is my code

```
global _start

section .data
    sys_read     equ 3
    sys_write    equ 4
    max_line_len equ 10
    stdin        equ 0      
    oneStr       db '1'
    oneStrLen    equ $ - oneStr

section .bss
    line resb 10

segment .text

_start:
    call _readLine           ; stores value in line
    cmp eax, dword 2         ; if input has length of 2, print out '1'
    je _printOne             ; No error if "call _printOne"!
    mov     eax, 01h         ; exit()
    xor     ebx, ebx         ; errno
    int     80h

_readLine:        
    mov eax, sys_read        ; syscall to read
    mov ebx, stdin           ; stdin
    mov ecx, line        ; put line into ecx
    mov edx, max_line_len    ; length to read
    int 0x80
    ret

_printOne:  
    mov eax, sys_write
    mov ebx, stdout
    mov ecx, oneStr
    mov edx, oneStrLen
    int 80h
    ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply leave out the `RET` at the end, the processor will try to execute whatever garbage is after your code in memory, that's probably causing the fault.

If you want to make a conditional call, just reverse the condition and jump over the call, such as:

```
    cmp eax, dword 2
    jne skip_print
    call _printOne
skip_print:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
```

If you don't want to make `_printOne` into a procedure, you should provide a way for execution to continue sensibly, such as by jumping back to exit, as follows:

```
    cmp eax, dword 2
    je _printOne
exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
    ...
_printOne:
    mov eax, sys_write
    mov ebx, stdout
    mov ecx, oneStr
    mov edx, oneStrLen
    int 80h
    jmp exit
```

Finally, an advice: do not use ideone to learn assembly programming. Set up an environment locally, in particular make sure you have a debugger where you can single step your code and see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. The reason I'm using ideone is because we have competitions at work and we have to provide an ideone link to our solution; also my work comp runs windows, whereas the ideone nasm in in Linux